# Magento 2 : how to display page content in both language

Tags: magento2, multistore

http://divyesh.suitshq.com/en/womens-lava-bracelet.html

using magento 2.1.0

When I change language its not changes some words in to page like Add to cart, Right sidebar details, Review tab form etc.

I need to convert whole page in Icelandic when I change language.

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure, that you have translates for all php constants in .csv file? Try to run

```
bin/magento i18n:pack %PATH TO .csv% %LOCALE CODE%
```

and then run

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy %LOCALE CODE%
```